# VxWorks booting problems(starting at 0x308000...)

Tags: vxworks

I want to install vxworks on target pc, but when i booted vxworks operating system, it suspended at [starting at 0x308000...], and no other responses were shown on the screen. How can I diagnose what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a COM Port?  By default, vxWorks uses the serial link to do IO.
The VGA Port is only used during startup.

There is a component (PC_CONSOLE?) which allow using VGA/KBD port for I/O.

In general, the more details you provide (vxworks verions, type of target, boot method, etc, etc...) the better answers you'll get...

You could also contact Wind River support...

Answer (score 0):

Look at config.h in your BSP and make sure it is setup to compile the kernel to load at address 0x308000. It could be that your bootloader and your OS are not in sync. Also look at the BSP developers guide for more information about what all of the #defines in config.h mean. Specifically: `RAM_LOW_ADR`, `LOCAL_MEM_LOCAL_ADRS`, and `ROM_BASE_ADR`, and make sure they are correct. It has been a while since I have looked at vxworks code, and I no longer have access to it... so it is hard for me to be more specific.